# Java formating date output from db table

Tags: java, date

Ok, first to say that I've been searching few days on how to resolve this problem and I've tried million ways but I think that neither of that working for me, or I'm missing something.

I have a db table with a column type date.
I have model class with a field `Date`.

```
public class Pacijent {
    //..
    private Date datum;
    //getters and setters 
}
```

And a `Data` access object for retrieving  and storing into a model class like this:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    Pacijent pacijent = new Pacijent();
    //..
    pacijent.setDatum(rs.getDate("datum"));
    //..
    pacijents.add(pacijent);
}
```

Next I set set attribute in controller and retrieve it in jsp page like `${param.paramName}`

The problem is that it outputs in `yyyy-MM-dd` and I want it to show in `dd-MM-yyyy`. Can you please guide me how do I format that in a right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSTL fmt` library has a `formatDate` tag for just this purpose.  To use it, first put this directive in the `<head>` element of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Then in the body of the page you can write something like

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
```

The doc, such as it is, for `fmt:formatDate` is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html). You may also need the info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
in order to figure out how to construct an appropriate format pattern.

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be optimal, but one option would be to expose a string getter in your `Pacijent` class which uses a `SimpleDateFormat` to generate the date string in the format you want for your presentation:

```
class Pacijent {
    // other content

    public String getDateFormatted() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
        String date = sdf.format(datum);
        return date;
    }
}
```

Then, access this getter from your JSP.